# Visual Studio 2012 Web Essentials 3.7 LESS "variable ... is undefined"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I have VS 2012 Premium Update 4 with the recently released (25 Feb 2014) Web Essentials 3.7 for compiling LESS files.

I'm customizing (Twitter) Bootstrap frontend framework by adding my own custom LESS-files to the compilation process:

I have this folder structure:

```
main-file.less
bootstrap/
    less/
        [all bootstrap .less files]
    custom/
        custom-mixins.less
        custom-other.less
        custom-variables.less
```

In `main-file.less` I have:

```
@import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/custom/custom-variables";
@import "bootstrap/custom/custom-mixins";
@import "bootstrap/custom/custom-other";
```

It appears to make no difference whether I apply the ".less" extensions in the import directives or not.

When compiling `main-files.less`, I keep getting errors like:

```
variable @my-label-color is undefined
variable @grid-gutter-width is undefined
```

**Any ideas for what might be wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the import order is incorrect.  Find out where those variables are defined and make sure that file is imported before the file where the variables are used.

**Update**

As correctly stated by `seven-phases-max`  variables can be defined after they are used.  Therefore more than likely you are using these two variables without actually assigning a value to them or defining them.

It maybe they are defined in a less file which you have not imported.  Check where these variables are defined and ensure they are in `main-files.less`

Comment: Less variables can be used before defined so the error is unlikely related to the import order.